# Frameworks para geração de relatórios Java

Tags: java, framework, relatório, ireport, jasper-reports

Bom dia.

Gostaria de saber se além do JasperReports com o iReports existe outro framework de geração de relatórios que vocês me recomendariam. Qual seria? Preciso de no mínimo 2 frameworks, um deles já tenho.

Agradeço desde já.

Comment: Stimulsoft. http://www.stimulsoft.com/en/products/reports-fx-java (É bem caro)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DynamicReports: http://www.dynamicreports.org/

> DynamicReports é baseado no JasperReports. Ele permite criar projetos de relatórios dinâmicos e ele não precisa de um relatório designer visual. Você pode criar muito rapidamente relatórios e produzir documentos que podem ser visualizados, impressos ou exportados em muitos formatos populares, como PDF, Excel, Word e outros.

Open Reports: http://oreports.com/

> OpenReports é uma solução de relatórios web poderoso, flexível e fácil de usar open source que fornece com base no navegador, parâmetro impulsionado, geração de relatórios dinâmica e recursos de agendamento de relatórios flexíveis.

FreeReportBuilder: http://frb.sourceforge.net/

> FreeReportBuilder é uma aplicação para criar um relatório simples rapidamente.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela sua resposta @Giovani Raci Paganini.

Answer (score 2):

Plugin Birt para eclipse http://eclipse.org/birt/

Ele é quase igual ao Japser Report, bem mais intuitivo pois é WYSIWYG, também drag'n'drop.

Comment: Muito obrigado @fsi

Answer (score 1):

Se você precisar de BI, use o Pentaho:

http://community.pentaho.com/projects/reporting/

Tutorial do Ambiente Livre:

http://www.ambientelivre.com.br/tutoriais-pentaho-bi/criando-um-relatorio-no-pentaho-report-designer-com-multiplas-fontes-de-dados-usando-consultas-em-formulas.html

Comment: Muito obrigado @rsb2097